# Why do some lines connecting points of high symmetry not have a name?

Tags: solid-state-physics, symmetry, crystals

[This page](http://lampx.tugraz.at/%7Ehadley/ss1/bzones/) lists a few Brillouin-Zones. You can click on them and see a 3D model you can rotate. I noticed that some lines connecting points of high symmetry have special names, others don't. <s>Are they simply missing or is there a reason these are not listed?</s> Why don't these lines have names?

## Edit

Take for example the line connecting the points L and K of the [fcc Brillouin-Zone](http://lampx.tugraz.at/%7Ehadley/ss1/bzones/fcc.php). On [google images](https://www.google.com/search?q=fcc%20brillouin%20zone) you will find many images of the Brillouin-Zone, but none of the images shows names for this line.

Comment: Did you read the line at the bottom of the page you linked?

Comment: @JonCuster Yes, I have. I have updated my question.

Comment: I'll also say that I've never seen names used for the lines, only for the high symmetry points in $k$ space. So I wouldn't worry about it too much - you won't find line names used in papers or textbooks.